# evaluate but not execute environment variable

Tags: bash, shell

Say I have an env variable:

```
export foo="bar";
declare z="\$foo";
```

I want to echo the value of "$z", which should be "bar". But if I run:

```
 echo "$z"
```

I get this literal:

```
$foo
```

and if I run this instead:

```
echo "$(eval "$z")"
```

I get `bar is not a command`.

But instead I am looking to just get

```
"bar"
```

as the echoed result.
How can I do that?

Comment: Sounds like what you want is indirect expansion. See [BashFAQ #6](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/006#Evaluating_indirect.2Freference_variables)

Comment: (I've updated the link to point more directly to the part of the FAQ that's on-topic for your question, if you followed it earlier).

Comment: If you run `foo=bar; bar=baz`, then `echo "$foo"` will emit `bar`, but `echo "${!foo}"` will emit `baz`.

Comment: Note that you need to put `lmx_setting_a`, not `$lmx_setting_a`, inside your variable; the `$` is a sigil that tells the shell to do parameter expansion, not part of the variable name itself.

Comment: already closed-as-dupe -- so the question is serving as a guidepost to prior instances; no need for it to have its own answer when those answers already exist on the prior copies.